# Create a popover to save selected text in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popover

I am creating a Chrome extension and want to create a popover (see the image) for when some text is selected and save that text in the extension.
[I want a popover like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpRx9.png)

So far I have created the extension and have a content script that displays a modal when some text is selected and I also know how to save the selected text using message passing. Instead of a modal I want to display a popover like in the above image.

```
// Content.js

import type { PlasmoCSConfig } from "plasmo"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const getSelectedText = () => window.getSelection().toString()

// Dialog
const getDialog = () => {
  var dialog = document.createElement("div")
  dialog.textContent = "This is a dialog"
  //   var button = document.createElement("button")
  //   button.textContent = "Close"
  //   dialog.appendChild(button)

  document.body.appendChild(dialog)
  //   document.getElementById("div").style.display = "block"
  dialog.showModal()

  document.addEventListener("click", function () {
    dialog.close()
    // document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none"
  })
}

document.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  if (getSelectedText().length > 0) {
    getDialog()
  } else {
    // Console log edge cases
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. And, it was pretty simple. (1) Create a div (2)
attach it to the document (3) Relocate to the selected location.

You can check out the complete code [here](https://github.com/dhruvmehra/recollect_extension)

Comment: The link doesnt work